# JAVA EE / RESTful - JAX-RS and JSON throw SQLException for Class.forName(...ClientDriver)

Tags: java, json, jdbc, jax-rs, restful-authentication

I build a some modularize project in java , with 5 layers. 
1-st layer - Bean (classes) 
2-nd layer - DaoDB (classes) 
3-rd layer - Dao (interfaces) - it's a bright (from façade to DaoDB)
4-th layer - façade (classes) - business logic
and 
5-th layer - Dynamic Web Project with JAX-RS and JSON
 
 
I have a problem with my login method in 5-th layer.

```
@Path("/web-project")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class AdminService{

private Company companyBean;

private AdminFacade getAdminFacade(HttpServletRequest req) {
    AdminFacade facade = ((AdminFacade) req.getSession().getAttribute("adminFacade"));
    return facade;
}

@Path("/login")
@POST
public Message adminLogin(LogInBean lgb, @Context HttpServletRequest req) throws UserSystemException, ClassNotFoundException {

    // Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");

    CouponClientFacade facade=CouponSystem.getInstance().login(lgb.getLogin(), lgb.getPassword(), "Admin");

    HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);
    session.setAttribute("adminFacade", facade);
    return new Message("logged in successfully as admin");
}
.....
.....
```

The problem with database - ClientDriver. I get SQLException when I try to add a new company. If I'm not using with the `Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");` and when I try to run others (CRUD) methods - for example

```
@Path("/createnewcompany")
@POST
public Message addCompany(Company cb, @Context HttpServletRequest req) throws UserSystemException {
    getAdminFacade(req).createCompany(cb);
    return new Message("created a new company: " + cb.getCompName());
}
```

I get an exception but, if I go to the façade layer and try to run all CRUD method they works alright.

Why JAX-RS does not to work with the client driver that written in first layer?

And JAX-RS and JSON works alright when I explicitly write on the client login method the implementation of the driver -  `Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");`, only.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

So your facades are singletons and stateful, and your web layer is stateless and request-scoped.

So within every request, it's a new thread, and it's possible that the driver is thread-bound. 
This is the case with oracle:

> Associating Connections with Threads
>
> To associate connections with a thread, set the Associate With Thread attribute to true. The default is false. A true setting allows connections to be saved as ThreadLocal in the calling thread. Connections get reclaimed only when the calling thread dies or when the calling thread is not in use and the pool has run out of connections. If the setting is false, the thread must obtain a connection from the pool each time the thread requires a connection.

As an aside, with your tiered architecture, your webtier shouldn't do anything with the database anyway, right? (it should only do validation and input/output translation. Actual business logic should call the database layer to do database operations)

Comment: Yes, it's true and this is the case.

Comment: If I remove comments from  // Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
the system works nice. I think that the good way do not use with the ClientDriver in my web module. And if I comment it, then I have an exception .